# Ideal way to chain asynchronous calls with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I would like to make an API call with axios based on the response of an initial API call - is this possible with asynchronous functions?

I have tried something along the following lines with await/promise:

```
function get_user(value){
  return axios.get( "https://apicall/" + value )
}

function get_user_posts(username){
  return axios.get("https://apicall/" + username)
}

var UsersOutput = async function () {
  const userProfile = await get_user(2928928);
  const userPosts = await get_user_posts(userProfile.data.username);
  return { userProfile, userPosts }
}
```

But this appears to return nothing, from either calls. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, that's the point of async/await. The question cannot be answered. What does 'nothing' mean? `undefined`? `null`? You're the only person who can debug calls and figure out what's wrong. It's unknown how you use UsersOutput. Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. If this is possible with static JSON files then, please, provide a workable demo that uses them.

Comment: This is the ideal way these days. str's question is that the `UsersOutput` will return a Promise object. So the call to that function should look like this: `UsersOutput().then(...)`. If not, that could be one problem. Otherwise, as Estus points out, it could be an AJAX issue. We don't have enough info.

Comment: "But this appears to return nothing" — How are you determining this? You don't even call `UsersOutput` in your example code, let alone examine what it returns.

Comment: Variable names starting with capital letters are traditionally used for constructor functions in JavaScript, since you aren't writing a constructor function you should call it `usersOutput`

Answer (score 0):

You first two functions return promices, not actual data. You should try something like this:

```
async function get_user(value){
  return (await axios.get( "https://apicall/" + value )).data;
}

async function get_user_posts(username){
  return (await axios.get("https://apicall/" + username)).data;
}
```

Or, if you keep first two functions unchanged:

```
var UsersOutput = async function () {
  const userProfile = (await get_user(2928928)).data;
  const userPosts = (await get_user_posts(userProfile.data.username)).data;
  return { userProfile, userPosts }
}
```

I, personally, find the first option better, because your getter functions return objects not promices, so you don't clutter your code with `(await   ).data;`. But it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to look on this link.
https://javascript.info/async-await

In your case you can use the .then() but I still prefer to use async await

By using await in async function you can chain some different actions and use the last call in your current